# Redirect user on page on click link from google results to some URL

Tags: javascript, redirect

I want to do some logic if user click my website in google results and go to my website then when he click one of links on website then he is redirect to some url (eg `https://example.com`)

I tried this way:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>

    var ref = document.referrer;
    document.write('document.referrer: ' + ref)

    $("a").click(function() { 
            
        if (ref === "https://www.google.com/" || ref === "https://www.google.pl/") {
            window.location.href = "https://example.com";
        }
    });

</script>
```

but this version redirect to normal link target not to `example.com`. How can I improve this?

Now this works only when my link on website have `target="_blank"` then it redirects to `example.com` in main window and in new window redirect to website link location.

Comment: you post link to question without answer

Comment: I should have edited the automated comment to clarify that it's your self-duplicate question because this question from Webmasters.SE was migrated to Stack Overflow.